# Site Percolation and S-clusters with $n\times m$ grid where $n\not =m$?

Tags: terminology, percolation

Consider a site percolation but change the dimension of the lattice from $n\times n$ to $n\times m$ where $n\not = m.$ [S-clusters](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/s-Cluster.html) are defined for $n\times n$ lattice. The occupation of each site are independent of each other.

*Example about site percolation with $m=n$, a square lattice.*

> [image]

*Example about site percolation where $m\not =n$, non-square lattice.*

> [image]

**Is the non-square model still called site percolation?**

*P.s. Super interesting site percolation programming [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120354/finding-all-minimal-paths-in-site-percolation) for the shortest path.*

Comment: @Masi added two small demos where the first example is a traditional site percolation on $n\times n$ grid while the second with different sized grid.

Comment: Is your second an answer to your question? It is non-square grid with perculation. So Yes, there is non-square model still called site percolation.

Comment: @Masi yes I think partially -- but if most research is on $m=n$ grids, the results are probably very different in choosing different grid sizes.

Comment: If $m = n$, then it is a square grid. Please, make the body clearer what you mean. Specify which grid type you have the problem. Is perculation failing with some grid types?

Comment: RSW theory is the study of crossing probabilities on, say finite rectangles with different form factors. This was a key to prove the conformal invariance of the site hexagonal lattice. Have a look at the lecture notes of Hugo Duminil-Copin or Ariel Yadin on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

You want to read on Russo-Seymour-Welsh (RSW) theorem:

> *"**The Russo-Seymour-Welsh (RSW) theory** is one of the most important tools in the study of planar percolation. A RSW-result generally refers to an inequality that **provides a bound on the probability to cross rectangles in the long direction**"* [Source](http://www.unige.ch/~tassion/fichiersPDF/voronoi.pdf).

and Antoined P:

> *"This was a key to prove the conformal invariance of the site hexagonal lattice. Have a look at the lecture notes of Hugo Duminil-Copin or Ariel Yadin on the matter."*

- [Ariel Yadin](https://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Yadin_A/0/1/0/all/0/1) in Arxiv and his [lectures](https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~yadina/)
- [Hugo Duminil-Copin](https://arxiv.org/a/duminilcopin_h_1.html) in Arxiv and [Hugo's lectures](http://www.unige.ch/~duminil/publicationlist.html)

---

**RSW Theorem**

- https://www.unige.ch/~duminil/publi/2015IAMPproceedings.pdf
- http://www.unige.ch/~tassion/fichiersPDF/voronoi.pdf